# How to convert .npy(numpy) file to .png file where .npy array shape (30,256,256)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I want to convert .npy file to .png file

```
from scipy.misc import toimage, imsave
img_array = np.load('MRNet-v1.0/train/sagittal/0003.npy')
print(img_array.shape)
name = "img"+str(i)+".png"
imsave(name,img_array)
```

shape : (30,256,256)

But getting error like

ValueError: 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.

Comment: This data is not image data(Or at least it is not single image). If it is multiple images data then first split the data into multiple array and save the images one by one.

Comment: Maybe your array represents 30 slices of a 256x256 pixel image. In which case, you'll either need to save it as 30 separate images, or save them in a format such as TIFF which allows multiple images in a single file.

Comment: Or ten color images...

Comment: @MadPhysicist but these likely would have the shape `[10,256,256,3]` (or `[3,256,256,10]`), no?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these `scipy` image tools are **deprecated** and will be removed in the future (beginning at scipy version 1.2.0). Instead, install `imageio` and then run:

```
import imageio
for i in range(30):
    imsave("./slice_{0}.png".format(i), img_array[i,...])
```